Python 3.10.12 - Cerberus v1.3.5 - validate error for - dict-->dict-->list - Is this possible to validate with Cerberus?
I need help to understand whether Cerberus v1.3.5 supports validation for the below YAML file. If yes, I would like to know what is wrong with schema I used below.
This YAML file is a test file which is part of the bigger YAML file.
In the YAML file, "myDictOne" and "myListOne" should be there and named like that (test names). All others are variables. Therefore, in the validation schema, both "myDictOne" and "myListOne" should be there.
With the schema that I have defined to validate this YAML file, it gives the error "There's no handler for 'abc' in the 'validate' domain".
Can someone please help with the correct "schema" to validate this test YAML file?
Schema used:
schema = { 'myDictOne': { 'type': 'dict', 'required': True, 'schema': {
               'myListOne' : { 'type': 'list', 'required': True, 'schema': { 'abc': {'type': 'string', 'required': True}, 'xyz': {'type': 'string', 'required': True} } }, 
               'myListTwo' : { 'type': 'list', 'required': True, 'schema': { 'abc': {'type': 'string', 'required': True}, 'xyz': {'type': 'string', 'required': True} } }
               } } }

test-12-Apr.yaml file:
myDictOne:
  myListOne:
  - abc:
    - abcentry11
    - abcentry12
    xyz:
    - xyzentry11
    - xyzentry12
  - abc:
    - abcentry13
    xyz:
    - xyzentry13
  - abc:
    - abcentry14
    xyz:
    - xyzentry14
  myListTwo:
  - abc:
    - abcentry21
    - abcentry22
    xyz:
    - xyzentry21
    - xyzentry22
  - abc:
    - abcentry23
    xyz:
    - xyzentry23
  - abc:
    - abcentry24
    xyz:
    - xyzentry24

What and How I tried to test this validations:
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> from cerberus import Validator
>>> with open("test-12-Apr.yaml", 'r') as file:
...     myData = yaml.safe_load(file)
...
>>> myData
{'myDictOne': {'myListOne': [{'abc': ['abcentry11', 'abcentry12'], 'xyz': ['xyzentry11', 'xyzentry12']}, {'abc': ['abcentry13'], 'xyz': ['xyzentry13']}, {'abc': ['abcentry14'], 'xyz': ['xyzentry14']}], 'myListTwo': [{'abc': ['abcentry21', 'abcentry22'], 'xyz': ['xyzentry21', 'xyzentry22']}, {'abc': ['abcentry23'], 'xyz': ['xyzentry23']}, {'abc': ['abcentry24'], 'xyz': ['xyzentry24']}]}}
>>>
>>> schema = { 'myDictOne': { 'type': 'dict', 'required': True, 'schema': {
...                'myListOne' : { 'type': 'list', 'required': True, 'schema': { 'abc': {'type': 'string', 'required': True}, 'xyz': {'type': 'string', 'required': True} } },
...                'myListTwo' : { 'type': 'list', 'required': True, 'schema': { 'abc': {'type': 'string', 'required': True}, 'xyz': {'type': 'string', 'required': True} } }
...                } } }
>>>
>>> v = Validator(schema)
>>> v.validate(myData)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1040, in validate
    self.__validate_definitions(definitions, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1110, in __validate_definitions
    result = validate_rule(rule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1085, in validate_rule
    return validator(definitions.get(rule, None), field, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1491, in _validate_schema
    self.__validate_schema_mapping(field, schema, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1504, in __validate_schema_mapping
    if not validator(value, update=self.update, normalize=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1040, in validate
    self.__validate_definitions(definitions, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1110, in __validate_definitions
    result = validate_rule(rule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1085, in validate_rule
    return validator(definitions.get(rule, None), field, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1489, in _validate_schema
    self.__validate_schema_sequence(field, schema, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1518, in __validate_schema_sequence
    validator(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1040, in validate
    self.__validate_definitions(definitions, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1110, in __validate_definitions
    result = validate_rule(rule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 1084, in validate_rule
    validator = self.__get_rule_handler('validate', rule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 366, in __get_rule_handler
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: There's no handler for 'abc' in the 'validate' domain.
>>>


please amend the syntax errors in the code so
that other users can reproduce the problem quickly:
minimal reproducible example
